# Login into alfresco cmis through SSO from spring web application

Tags: spring-mvc, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I am new to Alfresco CMIS , any how i am interacting with alfresco CMIS with Apache CMIS java api documentation from my spring mvc application.

Now my problem is I want to login into alfresco cmis without username and password after login into my spring application and I don't want to create users in alfresco cmis.Is it possible or not . If it is possible please suggest me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you think to create your account and store it in your database ??? and using it.

Comment: Exactly what ever you think

Comment: I think to create a small table store your data (username,password) in it and use it to log in and maintaining a connexion with it.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible with single sign on concept?

Comment: Single sign concept ???